# Emulated version of Twilight Princess has a strange water texture in Dolphin 4.0

Tags: technical-issues, macos, emulation, dolphin-emulator, zelda-twilight-princess

I have tried playing the GameCube version of Legend of Zelda: Twilight Princess on Dolphin 4.0-5973 for Mac. My problem is that water has weird lines over it that look like this:

[image: glitched water texture 1]

However, when I swim, the water shows the correct way:

[image: glitched water texture 2]

My biggest problem is that when I go underwater, this happens (referring to the lines blocking everything):

[image: glitched water texture 3]

This makes it almost impossible to play any part of the game which has water puzzles. How can I solve this?

Comment: You could try [a newer revision](https://dolphin-emu.org/download/) of the emulator and see if the issue is fixed. Generally speaking, whenever an emulator has troubles rendering a game properly, there's little the user can do on his end aside from messing with the configs until he finds one that works. But my guess is the problem might just be related with OSX. Since Dolphin's devs mostly use Linux, and most users have Windows, OSX is often left out with the most issues of all systems. If you don't find your answer here, you can always try the [Dolphin forums](https://forums.dolphin-emu.org/)

Comment: By the way: For a popular game like this one, Dolphin should normally have some special config files just for it out of the box, so messing with the configs yourself will likely not fix very much.

Comment: @Nolonar Actually messing with the configs themselves is the most OP can do, Dolphin relies heavily in the machine current setup. Sometimes tweaking dolphin requires a lot of trial and error. And even then it might not work, [this](https://wiki.dolphin-emu.org/index.php?title=The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Twilight_Princess_%28GC%29) is your best shot at common issues. Notice that although Twilight Princess is a popular game, it's compatibility it's still at 4 stars.

Comment: @BitcoinM I am quite familiar with Dolphin, and I also had been playing Twilight Princess, albeit I never got far enough to see your water issues. Have you changed anything in `Options > Graphics Settings`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### This issue was fixed on March 10, 2016 with [Dolphin 4.0-9158](https://dolphin-emu.org/download/dev/master/4.0-9158/).

According to the official [Dolphin Progress Report for March 2016](https://dolphin-emu.org/blog/2016/04/01/dolphin-progress-report-march-2016/#40-9113-fix-many-os-x-graphical-issues-by-endrift-and-40-9158-workaround-os-x-video-driver-bug-2498307-by-sonicadvance1), this issue was caused by a bug in Apple's OS X Graphics Drivers. It was fixed by developers [endrift](https://github.com/endrift) and [Sonicadvance1](https://github.com/Sonicadvance1).

[image: Before] [image: After]